# Pandas: move values from one column to an appropriate column

Tags: python, pandas

My google-fu is failing me. I have a simple dataframe that looks like this:

| Sample | Subject | Person | Place | Thing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | Janet |  |  |  |
| 1-1 | Boston |  |  |  |
| 1-1 | Hat |  |  |  |
| 1-2 | Chris |  |  |  |
| 1-2 | Austin |  |  |  |
| 1-2 | Scarf |  |  |  |

I want the values in the subject column to move into their appropriate column so that I end up with something like this:

| Sample | Subject | Person | Place | Thing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | Janet | Janet | Boston | Hat |
| 1-2 | Chris | Chris | Austin | Scarf |

I've looked at pivot and transpose, but those don't seem right.

Any ideas would be appreciated! :)

Comment: so its always the same pattern, person, city and thing?

Comment: are the person/place/thing always in the same order?

Comment: Same pattern, same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the groups are sorted and the pattern is always the same (no missing values), then reshape with numpy:

```
cols = ['Person', 'Place', 'Thing']

out = df.loc[::len(cols), ['Sample']].reset_index(drop=True)

out[cols] = df['Subject'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, len(cols))
```

For a more generic approach, only assuming that the categories are always in the same order within a group, identify the position per group with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the names, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
order = ['Person', 'Place', 'Thing']

out = (df.assign(col=df.groupby('Sample').cumcount()
                       .map(dict(enumerate(order))))
         .pivot(index='Sample', columns='col', values='Subject')
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Variant with [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
order = ['Person', 'Place', 'Thing']

out = (df.assign(col=df.groupby('Sample').cumcount())
         .pivot(index='Sample', columns='col', values='Subject')
         .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(order)))
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
  Sample Person   Place  Thing
0    1-1  Janet  Boston    Hat
1    1-2  Chris  Austin  Scarf
```

Finally, if you really want the "Subject" column, `insert` it:

```
out.insert(1, 'Subject', out['Person'])

print(out)

  Sample Subject Person   Place  Thing
0    1-1   Janet  Janet  Boston    Hat
1    1-2   Chris  Chris  Austin  Scarf
```

##### timings

If you can use the numpy approach, it's more strict on the input but much faster:

[image]

Comment: The second suggestion worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @Heather but not the first one? Are the groups sorted (e.g. 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2B, 2C…)? The first one requires a strict input but should be quite faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby("Sample")["Subject"]
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([*x], index=["Person", "Place", "Thing"]))
    .unstack(level=1)
).reset_index()

# If `Subject` column is required, then:
# out["Subject"] = out["Person"]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  Sample Person   Place  Thing
0    1-1  Janet  Boston    Hat
1    1-2  Chris  Austin  Scarf
```

Comment: Have you tested how it scales? `apply`+`Series([*x])` is likely not cheap